# Autocompleter tag of struts2-dojo is not working with struts2-jquery tags

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-autocompleter-example/) helped me to perform autocompleter in struts2. Through this tag i could

A> Show **list** form **database**

B> Insert value in **database** which were not in **list**

All worked fined..

But, now i have to use **struts2-jquery plugin** to show that page containing ****dojo*** tag* in a **pop-up window**. On doing so, the pop up window just appears, and the page is redirected to the form's action. This problem was solved when i removed the **dojo tag-sx**  from the **head** of that page. 
   Now the pop up is shown, but i can't insert value which are not in my list. i.e i can't perform the second option mentioned(B)

I've checked this [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action), but **struts2-jquery autocompleter** tag also couldn't fulfill my second option(B) as it adds an **_widget** in it's **name**  field

How can i fulfill both option in my case? Thanks in advance

Comment: Choose either jQuery or Dojo and then ask specific question about specific problem.

Comment: I have to choose Jquery as i have to display a pop-up window but, autocompleter tag of jquery doesn't gives be option B, which i could easily achieved form dojo tag.

Comment: so my question is how can i obtain option B using struts2-jquery tag?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Insert value in database which were not in list"? Explain and show some code.

Comment: +1 for Showcase link... really nice !

Comment: @AleksandrM What i mean is, through autocompleter tag(struts2-dojo) i can insert any value in the dropdown field, ie values which are not in the list. Check my first link for an example. I want to perform simialar operation with autocompleter tag of struts2-jquery. So my question is can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean submit any value that was not originally in the `autocompleter` list then `<sj:autocompleter>` tag has `forceValidOption` attribute for that. See this issue for more information http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=587.

Comment: Thanks!! I found the solution of my problem..:)